# How to set MS Kestrel Web Server to handle requests async and handle multiple requests without blocking

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, kestrel-http-server

I am testing an ASP.NET Core Web Application using MVC and WebApi and Kestrel Web Server.

```
   var host = new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseKestrel(opt => opt.ThreadCount = 10)
      .UseConfiguration(config)
      .UseContentRoot(path)
      .UseStartup<Startup>()
      .Build();
```

For some reason when the server is processing a request it will not accept in any new requests.  From what I have read this should not be the case but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my WebApi controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/test/{moduleid}")]
public Task<object> Api(string moduleId, [FromBody] JObject data)
{
    return Task.Run( () =>
    {
        return domain.Handle(moduleId, data);
    });
}
```

The code is not Async so I am wrapping in a Task.Run call.  Everything works but the server blocks new requests until the current request finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Kestrel is async by design.  I was using a client that limited to one request at a time (Postman).  Once I used multiple clients I saw all was well.